# How to make time slot multi select based on specefic service

Tags: php, calendar

I need your help with the following issue. I'm New in PHP and I'm building a booking Calendar for a website that makes user book service, my website is a spa website, so my task is to make a calendar with time slots, I made the calendar and time slots, ***The problem is how to make the time slots multi selectable based on specific service.***
For Example, I have three services:

1. service 1
2. service 2
3. service 3

if the user selects **service 1** for example, can book a **single slot time** for 3 or 4 times, and so on in other services.

I hope that I explained my problem.

Here is my Code for Time Slots and the output:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
        $date = $_GET['date'];
    }


    // Making Timelots >> Part 3
    $duration = 90;
    $cleanup = 30;
    $start = "10:00";
    $end = '24:00';

    function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end)
    {
        $start = new DateTime($start);
        $end = new DateTime($end);
        $interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $duration . 'M');
        $cleanupinterval = new DateInterval('PT' . $cleanup . 'M');
        $slots = array();

        for ($intStart = $start; $intStart < $end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupinterval)) {
            $endperiod = clone $intStart;
            $endperiod->add($interval);
            if ($endperiod > $end) {
                break;
            }
            $slots[] = $intStart->format('H:iA') . '-' . $endperiod->format('H:iA');
        }

        return $slots;
    }

    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            @media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
            (min-device-width: 802px) and (max-device-width: 1020px) {

                /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
                table,
                thead,
                tbody,
                th,
                td,
                tr {
                    display: block;

                }

                .empty {
                    display: none;
                }

                /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
                th {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: -9999px;
                    left: -9999px;
                }

                tr {
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                }

                td {
                    /* Behave  like a "row" */
                    border: none;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                    position: relative;
                    padding-left: 50%;
                }



                /*
    Label the data
    */
                td:nth-of-type(1):before {
                    content: "Sunday";
                }

                td:nth-of-type(2):before {
                    content: "Monday";
                }

                td:nth-of-type(3):before {
                    content: "Tuesday";
                }

                td:nth-of-type(4):before {
                    content: "Wednesday";
                }

                td:nth-of-type(5):before {
                    content: "Thursday";
                }

                td:nth-of-type(6):before {
                    content: "Friday";
                }

                td:nth-of-type(7):before {
                    content: "Saturday";
                }


            }

            /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

            @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
                body {
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
            }

            /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

            @media only screen and (min-device-width: 802px) and (max-device-width: 1020px) {
                body {
                    width: 495px;
                }
            }

            @media (min-width:641px) {
                table {
                    table-layout: fixed;
                }

                td {
                    width: 33%;
                }
            }

            .row {
                margin-top: 20px;
            }

            .today {
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Book for Date: <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date)); ?></h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- part 4 -->
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : ''; ?>
                </div>
                <!-- Part 3 -->
                <?php
                $timesolts = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
                foreach ($timesolts as $ts) {
                ?>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Part 4 -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Booking: <span id="slot"></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <form action="" method="POST">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">Time Slot</label>
                                        <input required type="text" readonly name="timeslot" id="timeslot" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="">services</label>
                                        <input required type="text" readonly name="service" id="service" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                                        <input required type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input required type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                'use strict';
                $('.book').click(function() {
                    var timeslot = $(this).attr('data-timeslot');
                    $('#slot').html(timeslot);
                    $('#timeslot').val(timeslot);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

and the output is like this:
[image: view this image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using buttons to pick a time, use checkboxes instead. It's the right tool for the job, as it allow you to select and deselect multiple options.

Plus, with some CSS magic you can make them look like buttons by styling the label of the checkbox.

Look at the example below to see the output of these checkboxes.

### Edit

A pattern you could use is having `<fieldset>` elements paired with a `<legend>` and nested checkbox to make groups of fields. This way you can present your rooms per timeslot and let the user choose them this way. It makes the form pretty flexible as you can easily control what data is sent to the server.

To check if a timeslot has any available rooms you could set a flag (true or false) and store that with each timeslot. Then when you send the form to the backend it will check if all rooms have been reserved for that timeslot. If they have the, for example `$is_available` value would be false. This value could then be read in the template.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#room-form');

form.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.classList.contains('timeslot')) {
    const fieldset = target.closest('fieldset');
    fieldset.disabled = !target.checked;
    if (!target.checked) {
      const inputs = fieldset.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
      for (const input of inputs) {
        input.checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
});

/* Just for demonstration purposes */
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  console.clear();
  for (const [ name, value ] of formData) {
    console.log('Name:', name, '-', 'Value:', value);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
/* Just for demonstration purposes */
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

fieldset {
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

fieldset legend label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

fieldset legend label:hover {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

fieldset:disabled .room label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

button {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.room {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 0;
}

.room input {
  display: none;
}

.room label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.room input:checked + label {
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form id="room-form">
  <fieldset disabled>
    <legend><label>10:00 - 12:00<input class="timeslot" type="checkbox" name="timeslot-10-12"/></label></legend>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-1-10-12" name="timeslot-10-12-room" value="1"/>
      <label for="room-1-10-12">Room 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-2-10-12" name="timeslot-10-12-room" value="2"/>
      <label for="room-2-10-12">Room 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-3-10-12" name="timeslot-10-12-room" value="3"/>
      <label for="room-3-10-12">Room 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-4-10-12" name="timeslot-10-12-room" value="4"/>
      <label for="room-4-10-12">Room 4</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <legend><label>12:00 - 14:00<input class="timeslot" type="checkbox" name="timeslot-12-14"/></label></legend>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-1-12-14" name="timeslot-12-14-room" value="1"/>
      <label for="room-1-12-14">Room 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-2-12-14" name="timeslot-12-14-room" value="2"/>
      <label for="room-2-12-14">Room 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-3-12-14" name="timeslot-12-14-room" value="3"/>
      <label for="room-3-12-14">Room 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-4-12-14" name="timeslot-12-14-room" value="4"/>
      <label for="room-4-12-14">Room 4</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <legend><label>14:00 - 16:00<input class="timeslot" type="checkbox" name="timeslot-14-16"/></label></legend>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-1-14-16" name="timeslot-14-16-room" value="1"/>
      <label for="room-1-14-16">Room 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-2-14-16" name="timeslot-14-16-room" value="2"/>
      <label for="room-2-14-16">Room 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-3-14-16" name="timeslot-14-16-room" value="3"/>
      <label for="room-3-14-16">Room 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="room">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-4-14-16" name="timeslot-14-16-room" value="4"/>
      <label for="room-4-14-16">Room 4</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks For replying and your effort.
But I mean how to select the same time for 3 or 4 times?

Comment: I'm confused. What is the point of selecting the same time 3 or 4 times? What should happen when you select it multiple times?

Comment: For Example:
I have Three Rooms, the rooms available from 10 AM to 2 PM, and the time slots for the three rooms are:

1- 10:00AM to 12:00PM
2- 12:00PM to 02:00PM

User 1 can select the first time for room 1, and the first time for room 2, and the first time for room 3. after that the first time is not available.

I Hope I explained my Purpose.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you give some feedback on it?

Comment: Thank You in advance, but it is not mu purpose

Comment: I would love some specific feedback on why this does not meet your purpose.

Comment: I Explained my purpose in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66199910/how-to-make-booked-or-hidden-in-time-slot

Comment: Ah well, assuming every *slot* has multiple rooms connected to it in the db; you could loop over the rooms per slot. If all rooms of that slot have been booked, disable the button. Or like I tried to explain above; when submitting the form check if all rooms of a selected slot are booked. Then save a value in the database saying it's fully booked. Then when you render your buttons you can read that value of the slot saying that its fully booked and disable the button. That's the gist.

Comment: But you'll need to be able to store the data for each slot in your database to do this. Currently you're creating your slots in the template and they don't have any db relation.