# How to make booked or hidden in time slot

Tags: php, calendar

I'm using this piece of code to make time slots:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date = $_GET['date'];
}


// Making Timelots >> Part 3
$duration = 90;
$cleanup = 30;
$start = "10:00";
$end = '24:00';

function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end)
{
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $duration . 'M');
    $cleanupinterval = new DateInterval('PT' . $cleanup . 'M');
    $slots = array();

    for ($intStart = $start; $intStart < $end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupinterval)) {
        $endperiod = clone $intStart;
        $endperiod->add($interval);
        if ($endperiod > $end) {
            break;
        }
        $slots[] = $intStart->format('H:iA') . '-' . $endperiod->format('H:iA');
    }

    return $slots;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
        (min-device-width: 802px) and (max-device-width: 1020px) {

            /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
            table,
            thead,
            tbody,
            th,
            td,
            tr {
                display: block;

            }

            .empty {
                display: none;
            }

            /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
            th {
                position: absolute;
                top: -9999px;
                left: -9999px;
            }

            tr {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            td {
                /* Behave  like a "row" */
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 50%;
            }



            /*
Label the data
*/
            td:nth-of-type(1):before {
                content: "Sunday";
            }

            td:nth-of-type(2):before {
                content: "Monday";
            }

            td:nth-of-type(3):before {
                content: "Tuesday";
            }

            td:nth-of-type(4):before {
                content: "Wednesday";
            }

            td:nth-of-type(5):before {
                content: "Thursday";
            }

            td:nth-of-type(6):before {
                content: "Friday";
            }

            td:nth-of-type(7):before {
                content: "Saturday";
            }


        }

        /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }

        /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 802px) and (max-device-width: 1020px) {
            body {
                width: 495px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width:641px) {
            table {
                table-layout: fixed;
            }

            td {
                width: 33%;
            }
        }

        .row {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .today {
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Book for Date: <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date)); ?></h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- part 4 -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : ''; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Part 3 -->
            <?php
            $timesolts = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
            foreach ($timesolts as $ts) {
            ?>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success book" data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Part 4 -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Booking: <span id="slot"></span></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Time Slot</label>
                                    <input required type="text" readonly name="timeslot" id="timeslot" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">services</label>
                                    <input required type="text" readonly name="service" id="service" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input required type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input required type="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            'use strict';
            $('.book').click(function() {
                var timeslot = $(this).attr('data-timeslot');
                $('#slot').html(timeslot);
                $('#timeslot').val(timeslot);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and using database to store the times in, my table name is **bookings** and it's looks like this:
[bookings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRCsk.png)

and made another table for services that I want to be booked and it is name is **services** and it's looks like this: [services table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQyk8.png)

and **service_id** box in table **bookings** referring to **id** box in **services**.

**What I want to make is something like out of stock in ecommerce**; I mean that when the service 1 in the table bookings booked for specific time slot, I want to display BOOKED instead of the time slot it self.

for example, I want the out put somthing like this: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6MrC.png)

So What shoud I do?

Comment: compare $ts with whats in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add count column in service table and decrease every booking operation  and when equal 0 show service is booked or
You can count number of service_id in booking table and add max count column in service table and when user book the service check if the count number of service_id in booking table is less than the max count coulmn

Comment: can you please ensure you include snippets rather than just saying "do the thing"